# usort difference php7.1 vs php5.6

Tags: php, php-7

I'm currently migrating a project from php5.6 to php7.1. Most is going well, but I just hit a wall on a test.

The function usort doesn't have the same behavior on both version, and it doesn't seem to be documented (it's not that two values are equals and then the order is undefined). In my test case, the returned array order is reversed.

Here is a reproduction of the problem. Note that I return -1 all the time for simplification (I'm focusing in the diff between PHP5.6 and 7 here)

Code run on both versions:

```
$a = [['value' => 1, 'toto' => 'toto'], ['value' => 1, 'toto' => null]];
usort($a, function ($a, $b) { return -1;});
print_r($a);
```

Results in PHP 5.6:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [value] => 1
            [toto] =>
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [value] => 1
            [toto] => toto
        )

)
```

PHP 7.1

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [value] => 1
            [toto] => toto
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [value] => 1
            [toto] =>
        )

)
```

Comment: That's because your callback function code `return -1;` is pretty meaningless, and totally subject to the order in which entries are compared..... you shouldn't be making that assumption, but should be using an actual comparison in your callback

Comment: For all intents and purposes the order of your items is *undefined*; you can't expect any particular result.

Comment: you should fully implement the compare function.

Comment: @MarkBaker do you mean that sorting everything the same way counts as returning 0 (as per the documentation) ?

Comment: If you [display `$a` and `$b` in your callback](https://3v4l.org/eesG5), so that you can see the order in which PHP5 makes its comparisons using your callback compared with PHP7, you can see the difference

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason for this is that in this case the values get passed to the `usort()` callback in different order depending on the PHP version.

https://3v4l.org/bW5WP

```
$array = ['a', 'b'];
usort($array, function ($firstValue, $secondValue) { echo "COMPARING: {$firstValue} with {$secondValue}\n"; return -1;});
```

PHP 5.6 output:

> COMPARING: b with a

PHP 7.x output:

> COMPARING: a with b

This doesn't matter to callbacks which actually compare the given values. Your callback however **always** returns `-1`, which means *first value is lesser than the second value*. In PHP 5.6 this results in `b` being first in the list, in PHP 7.x `a` will be first.

Returning incosistent results from the callback will result in undefined behavior if your callback is sorting an array of more than 2 values.

Comment: Fair enough, that explains it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In the [PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php)

> If two members compare as equal, their relative order in the sorted
>   array is undefined.

Also it is an inconsistency. [See Here](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=69158)

Comment: `–1` does not mean "equal"

Answer (score 0):

Been facing this issue as well.
This should work for both php5 and php7

```php
# source: comment by jasdeep at sikher dot com in https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=69158
<?php

// https://3v4l.org/0sTAW

function test($firstValue, $secondValue) {
    if ($firstValue > $secondValue) {
        return 1;
    }
    if ($firstValue < $secondValue) {
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}
$array = array('a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'c');
usort($array, 'test');
echo print_r($array);
```

### for your example

```
$a = [['value' => 1, 'toto' => 'toto'], ['value' => 1, 'toto' => null]];
usort($a, function ($a, $b) { 
    if ($a > $b) {
        return 1;
    }
    if ($a < $b) {
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
});

print_r($a);
```

> ##### Result for 7.4.33, 7.2.34, 7.2.31, 5.5.6:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [value] => 1
            [toto] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [value] => 1
            [toto] => toto
        )

)
```