# Twig_Error_Syntax for "Unknown filter" with a Twig filter in Timber

Tags: php, wordpress, twig, timber

This has got to be simple, but I can't see what's wrong. I'm using the simple filter example at https://twig.symfony.com/doc/1.x/advanced.html#filters with Twig 1.34 in Timber, a WordPress plugin.

I added

```
// an anonymous function
$filter = new Twig_SimpleFilter('rot13', function ($string) {
    return str_rot13($string);
});
```

and

```
$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader);
$twig->addFilter($filter);
```

to my theme's functions.php file.

But using `{{ 'Twig'|rot13 }}` in my view.twig file gives a fatal error

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Twig_Error_Syntax'
with message 'Unknown "rot13" filter' in view.twig
```

and a notice

```
Undefined variable: loader in functions.php
```

Using a filter like `{{ 'Twig'|lower }}` works OK.

Do I need to add the functions to functions.php in a different way?

Comment: I'd say yes, most likely you need to. Perhaps it's just no the correct place for that view.twig file.

Comment: OK, but how to do that is my question.

Comment: From what I read from the docs you do everything right. I think only the where to do that is not so clear (for me as well). So the how looks good to me honestly.

Comment: True, the docs are not clear about _where_ the php functions go. And there is a `global` function listed that "is like any other template variable, except that it's available in all templates and macros" but it's not clear how to use it.

Comment: What I know from Twig is that if the template (here: view.twig) is executed in that configured **Twig_Environment** that this works.

Comment: I also get a PHP notice "Undefined variable: loader in functions.php" so maybe the Twig_Environment is wrong?

Comment: Now that's a hint. `$loader` is not defined. You need to write that code where `$loader` is defined otherwise it can't work.

Comment: Only "render" I can find in the theme files that might be relevant is `Timber::render( $templates, $context );` is called in index.php. My view.twig is in /templates/view.twig.

Comment: @hakre thanks for the help. Now I'm back to my original question :)  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49805943/sorting-a-repeater-field-from-advanced-custom-fields-in-timber-twig

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to documentation [here](https://timber.github.io/docs/guides/extending-timber/#adding-to-twig) (title: **Adding to Twig**)

it should be done like this (in `functions.php`):

```
add_filter('timber/twig', function($twig) {
   $twig->addExtension(new Twig_Extension_StringLoader());

   // add Your filters here
   $twig->addFilter(
     new Twig_SimpleFilter(
       'rot13', 
       function($string) {
         return str_rot13($string);
       }
     )
   );
   // or simply: 
   // $twig->addFilter(new Twig_SimpleFilter('rot13', 'str_rot13'));

   $twig->addFilter(
     new Twig_SimpleFilter(
       'hello', 
       function($name) {
         return 'Hello, '.$name;
       }
     )
   );

   return $twig;
});
```

Comment: Ah, thanks! That make sense turning it into a full function. But I get a parse error right after `return str_rot13($string)`

Comment: @BlueDogRanch fixed, forgot to put semicolon at the end of line :D

Comment: Cool! Works perfectly. And now I know how to work on my earlier question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49805943/advanced-custom-fields-and-sorting-a-repeater-field-in-twig

Comment: @BlueDogRanch happy to be helpful

Comment: Well, trying a more complex filter breaks :(  Want to take a look at my older question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49805943/sorting-a-repeater-field-from-advanced-custom-fields-in-timber-twig

Comment: @BlueDogRanch not today) maybe tomorrow. As I understand You've to create a filter class from abstract Twig_Filter to achieve Your goal.