# How can I make a custom escaper for Twig via Timber?

Tags: php, wordpress, twig, timber

I'm using Twig and Timber within WordPress and I want to make a [custom escaper](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/1.x/filters/escape.html#custom-escapers) per Twig's documentation.

```
$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader);
$twig->getExtension('Twig_Extension_Core')->setEscaper('csv', 'csv_escaper');

// before Twig 1.26
$twig->getExtension('core')->setEscaper('csv', 'csv_escaper');
```

However, I'm not sure how to go about doing this when using Timber with it; I couldn't find any docs on doing this within Timber - is this possible without editing the core files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying DarkBee's answer I ended up finding [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49837032) on a similar question where they got the same error I was getting and after using the below code I got the custom filter working:

```
add_filter('timber/twig', 'blm_add_twig_custom_filters');

function blm_add_twig_custom_filters($twig) {
    $twig->addExtension(new Twig_Extension_StringLoader());
    $twig->addFilter(new Twig_SimpleFilter('e2', 'escape_no_double'));
    return $twig;
}

/* Custom twig/timber escaper so it doesn't double encode html entities */

function escape_no_double($str) {
    return htmlspecialchars($str, ENT_QUOTES | ENT_SUBSTITUTE, 'UTF-8', false);
}
```

More can be found [here](https://timber.github.io/docs/guides/extending-timber/#adding-to-twig).

Answer (score 1):

As seen in the [documentation](https://timber.github.io/docs/guides/functions/#make-functions-available-in-twig) you could use `add_filter` to add the escaper,

```
add_filter( 'timber/twig', function( \Twig_Environment $twig ) {
    $twig->getExtension('Twig_Extension_Core')->setEscaper('csv', 'csv_escaper');
    return $twig;
} );
```

Comment: Just got around to trying this but got an error that the filter wasn't found.